# wget to download Ubuntu Repo

Tags: repository, wget, localrepository

I'm setting up an offline Ubuntu Repo and I need to download the Ubuntu repo using a windows machine.  I have access to WGET.exe .  What is the command to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't know how wget works in widnows but in Ubuntu or Linux, you put it like this `wget andtheURLofthefile`, i suppose if Wget for windows allows you to put the URL of the files you want to download, well do that.

Comment: understood, I guess the part that i'm not sure of is what do I want to download (URL) for 10.04 supporting an i386 host.

Comment: Type `wget --help` or `man wget` for information about wget. The Ubuntu repository is huge, it contains over 55000 packages. You can use the --recursive to download all files in all directories.

Comment: @Anonymous he is Using Wget for Windows not in Ubuntu. Commands won't work.

Comment: The commands are the same.  help does work. I waned to know is what the address of the repository would be to download everything needed to support 10.04 i386 platform offline.  for instance what would the command using wget in linux to do this?  I can modify it to work in windows.

Comment: @UriHerrera wget should work the same on Windows, it's a command-line utility all the same.

Comment: Ah true, just used it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you should find a fast mirror geographically near you, example se.archive.ubuntu.com (Sweden) or no.archive.ubuntu.com (Norway), just put your country code instead of se or no so you can download fast.

Then `wget --recursive http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`

When you use the --recursive option wget fetches all files and everything in all the subdirectories.

However, the Ubuntu package repository is HUGE, so sure you have enough disk space.

Comment: where can I find a list of mirrors

Comment: @Lexicon, just use XX.archive.ubuntu.com where XX is a two-letter country code. See ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country codes.

Comment: @Anonymous, Can you say how HUGE is Ubuntu repository.Just a curiosity

Comment: @AnwarShah, around 40000 packages compiled for both 32-bit and 64-bit aswell as source code. Debian (of which Ubuntu is a derivative) is 73 CDs or 11 DVDs, so expect at least 50 gigabyte.

Comment: that command also downloads icons, html pages, etc, that are not part of the repository. Is there a better command?

Comment: adding "-A rpm" seems to reject anything that isn't an rpm